# i want that client can send private message also from a broadcast server socket python

Tags: python, sockets, server, chat, broadcast

i have made a broadcast server and client both and i have used a message as command like @private to work as a command and and that will list all users and then i want that it should select one of them and then it can only chat with those client only which he as selected and on the backend broadcast also work for others

**server()**

```
# import socket programming library
import socket
import time
# import thread module
from _thread import *
import threading

def chatwithtwo(c,username,numusr,data):
            c.send("choose to which one you wanna chat".encode())
            for i in range(len(username)):
                select=f"{i}. {username[i]}\n"
                c.send(select.encode())
            #here the thread gives problem
            select_username=c.recv(1024)
            print("select:",select_username.decode())
            try:
                if username[int(select_username)] in username:
                        chat_two_display(numusr,c,clients[int(select_username)])
                else:
                    c.send("wrong selection".encode())
            except:
                c.send("wrong input".encode())
            lock.release()
def chat_two_display(numusr,c,recver):
    sendcheck={}
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        sendcheck[numusr]=c
        for i in range(len(clients)):
            if clients[i]==recver:
                send_to=usernames[i]
        print(f"[+] {numusr} --> {send_to}:- {data.decode()}")
        chat_two_send(numusr,data.decode(),recver)
def chat_two_send(numusr,data,recver):
    sendingtoall=f"[+] {numusr} (private):- {data}"
    recver.send(sendingtoall.encode())

def send_data(numusr,senddata,clients,sendcheck):
    lock.release()
    for i in range(len(clients)):
        if not clients[i]==sendcheck[numusr]:
            sendingtoall=f"[+] {numusr}:- {senddata}"
            clients[i].sendall(sendingtoall.encode())
def display_data(c,numusr):
        global lock
        lock=threading.Lock()
        sendcheck={}
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            data = c.recv(1024)
            sendcheck[numusr]=c
            print(f"[+] {numusr}:- {data.decode()}")
            lock.acquire()
            if data.decode()=="@private":
                #thread.acquire()
                chatwithtwo(c,usernames,numusr,data)
                
            else:
                send_data(numusr,data.decode(),clients,sendcheck)
# thread function
def threaded(clients,username):
    for i in range(len(clients)):
        threading.Thread(target=display_data,args=(clients[i],username[i])).start()
def username_check(c):
    while True:
                uname=c.recv(1024)
                if uname.decode() not in usernames:
                    datatosend=f"your username is {uname.decode()}"
                    usernames.append(uname.decode())
                    clients.append(c)
                    c.sendall(datatosend.encode())
                    break
                else:
                    c.send("[-] This username is alredy in use!!!".encode())


def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"

    # reserve a port on your computer
    # in our case it is 12345 but it
    # can be anything
    port = 8000
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    print("socket binded to port", port)

    # put the socket into listening mode
    s.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening")
    global clients
    global usernames
    global threads
    clients=[]
    usernames=[]
    threads=[]
    connectio(s)

def connectio(s):
    while True:

        # establish connection with client
        c, addr = s.accept()

        # lock acquired by client
        print('Connected to :', addr[0], ':', addr[1])
        username_check(c)
        # Start a new thread and return its identifier
        threaded(clients,usernames)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**client()**

```
import socket
import threading
import time

def send_data(s):
    while True:
        message=input("")
        s.send(message.encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if message=="close":
            s.close()

def display_data(s):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(str(data.decode('ascii')))
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
def Main():
    # local host IP '127.0.0.1'
    host = '127.0.0.1'
 
    # Define the port on which you want to connect
    port = 8000
 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 
    # connect to server on local computer
    s.connect((host,port))
    while True:
        username=input("enter your username which should be unique:-")
        s.send(username.encode())
        username_check=s.recv(1024)
        print(username_check.decode())
        if username_check:
            if username_check.decode()!="Try again":
                break

    # message you send to server
    threading.Thread(target=send_data,args=(s,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=display_data,args=(s,)).start()
    # close the connection
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

i have called a function for it that is *chatwithtwo()* but the problem is when *select_username* variable is receiving the value other threads also work at the same time all that get messed up please help me out in that

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `for i in range(len(clients)):` this from threaded function and all done

it will run your thread every time a client will connect to the server like if one client is connected then it will run for 1 time threads=1 running then the second time will run then its value will be 2 and the loop will run twice and the thread value fill get added to the last one like now running thread is 1 and after loop 2 more will be added and now threads are 3 and so on.